# How do I make Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 wifi card work with Netgear WNR614 N300 Wi-Fi Router on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: wireless, xubuntu, router, netgear

How do I make Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 wifi card work with Netgear WNR614 N300 Wi-Fi Router on Ubuntu 16.04? The laptop is Dell Vostro 2520. Details of wireless card pasted at [ubuntupastebin](http://paste.ubuntu.com/23201126/)

Comment: I think what you really mean to ask is "How do I make Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 wifi card work"? ie, there are no Ubuntu drivers for your router to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: I tried many things including rm /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf. I don't know which of my action did it. So I can't post anything as an answer. Now it is working.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed wl?  This is the broadcom proprietary driver.

According to this link, your driver is supported by wl (broadcom sta driver) but not b43 (reverse engineered driver firmware extractor).

http://linuxwireless.org/en/users/Drivers/b43/#Supported_devices

To activate wifi for your BCM43142:

sudo apt install bcmwl-kernel-source